# Vue.js Router change url but not view

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I see this bug in console:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "product" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

My template id="productDetail" not receive the property "product" of the template id="product" I don't know how I can push this, please see my cod.

HTML LIST
That's ok when I click the router-link the url change to:

## /product/iphone-x-64-gb for example.

```
<template id="product" functional>
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="row">
        <li v-for="(product, index) in products" class="col l4 m6 s12">
            <div class="card-box">
                <div class="card-image">
                    <img :src="product.images" :alt="product.images" class="responsive-img"/>
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <h3><a href="#">{{ product.brand }}</a></h3>
                    <span class="price-used"><i class="used">{{ index }} gebrauchte Roomba 651</i></span>
                </div>
                <div class="card-action row">
                    <span class="col s6 price"><span>{{ product.price }}</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <router-link class="btn btn-default light-green darken-3" :to="{name: 'product', params: {product_id: product.id}}">meer detail</router-link>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

HTML PRODUCT DETAIL (THAT NO RECEIVE THE "product")

```
<template id="productDetail" functional>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6">
        <img src="images/iphone-8-64-gb.jpg" alt="product.images" class="responsive-img"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m6">
        <h3>{{ product.title }}</h3>
        <h5>{{ product.price }}<h5>
        <div class="col s12 m6">
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn light-green darken-3"><i class="material-icons left">add_shopping_cart</i>kopen</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col s12 m6">
            <router-link class="btn btn-default light-green darken-3" :to="{path: '/'}">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><i class="material-icons left">arrow_back</i>terug
            </router-link>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

THE .JS

```
var List = Vue.extend(
{
    template: '#product',
    data: function ()
    {
        return {products: [],};
    },
    created: function()
    {
        this.$http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/17528x').then(function(response) {
            this.products = response.body.products;
        }.bind(this));
    },

});

const Product =
{
    props: ['product_id'],
    template: '#productDetail'
}

var router = new VueRouter(
{
    routes: [
    {path: '/', component: List},
    {path: '/product/:product_id', component: Product, name: 'product'},
    ]
});


var app = new Vue(
{
    el: '#app',
    router: router,
    template: '<router-view></router-view>'
});
```

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your props should be `props: ['product']` instead of `props: ['product_id']`

---

```
<parent-component :product="product"></parent-component>
```

**ChildComponent.vue**

```
export default {
  name: 'child-component',
  props: ['product']
}
```

Comment: Very nice is correct, but now I need defined the "title" ofthe <h3>{{ product.title }}</h3> mmmmm...

Comment: [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"

Comment: Bind your `product` using v-bind:product="product" on the child component tag

Comment: I can try, but dont understand here... sorry

Comment: Would you like to close the issue by accepting an answer?

Answer (score 1):

First [activate `props` on the route](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html):

```js
var router = new VueRouter({
...
      path: '/product/:product_id',
      component: Product,
      name: 'product',
      props: true                    // <======= add this line
    },
...
```

Now the `product_id` will be set on the `Product` component.

So, you want to display the whole product information, but at this moment you only have the `product_id`. The solution is to fetch the product:

```js
const Product = {
  props: ['product_id'],
  template: '#productDetail',
  data: function() {                              // <============ Added from this line...
    return {
      product: {}     // add {} so no error is thrown while the product is being fetched
    };
  },
  created: function() {
    var productId = this.product_id;
    // if there is a URL that fetches a given product by ID, it would be better than this
    this.$http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/17528x').then(function(response) {
      this.product = response.body.products.find(function (product) { return product.id == productId });
    }.bind(this));
  }                                               // <============ ...to this line.
}
```

Check **[JSFiddle demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/rc2q5s22/)** of the solution above.

## Alternative solution: passing the whole `product` as prop

Pass the `product` in the `params:` (along with `product_id`):

```
<router-link class="btn btn-default light-green darken-3" :to="{name: 'product', 
             params: {product_id: product.id, product: product}}">meer detail</router-link>
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Activate `props` on the route](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html):

```js
var router = new VueRouter({
...
      path: '/product/:product_id',
      component: Product,
      name: 'product',
      props: true                    // <======= add this line
    },
...
```

Finally, add `product` so you can use it:

```
const Product = {
  props: ['product_id', 'product'],         // <======= added 'product' here
  template: '#productDetail'
}
```

[**Demo JSFiddle** for this solution here](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/rc2q5s22/4/).

Comment: Nice, nice, nice, your great! Thank you